# get new Value of div in function

Tags: javascript, file-upload, parameters

I want to get width and height of the displayed image inside an image wrapper to do stuff with it. The Image ist displayed when selected, so the size of the wrapper changes. Since I need the size of the wrapper to do other stuff I use it as parameters. So after updating the image I get the height and width of the OLD image wrapper. So how can I modify my code to get the new dimensions of the wrapper after displaying the new image?

(I don't need information about submitting or anything. This is a reduced version of the code.)

```
<div style="width:300px">
        <div id="image-wrapper" style="border:2px dashed blue">
            <img src="text.jpeg" id="image" style="width:100%">
        </div>
        <p>width: <span id="x"></span></p>
        <p>height: <span id="y"></span></p>
    </div>
    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" id="user-file" accept="image/jpeg, image/jpg, image/png, image/gif" onchange="Image.display(this, document.getElementById('image'));Image.ready(document.getElementById('image-wrapper'),document.getElementById('x'),document.getElementById('y'))">
        <button type="submit">Submit
        </button>
    </form>
<script>
    class Image {
        static display ( event, target ) {
            if ( event.files[0] ) {
                let fileReader = new FileReader();
                fileReader.onload = function (event) {
                    target.setAttribute( 'src', event.target.result );
                }
                fileReader.readAsDataURL(event.files[0]);
            }
        }

        static ready (wrapper, x, y) {
            x.innerHTML = wrapper.clientWidth;
            y.innerHTML = wrapper.clientHeight;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDITED**: You have to wait for the image to load and THEN call your `ready` method!

```html
<div style="width:300px">
        <div id="image-wrapper" style="border:2px dashed blue">
            <img src="text.jpeg" id="image" style="width:100%" onload="Image.ready(document.getElementById('image-wrapper'),document.getElementById('x'),document.getElementById('y'))">
        </div>
        <p>width: <span id="x"></span></p>
        <p>height: <span id="y"></span></p>
    </div>
    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" id="user-file" accept="image/jpeg, image/jpg, image/png, image/gif" onchange="Image.display(this, document.getElementById('image'));">
        <button type="submit">Submit
        </button>
    </form>
<script>
    class Image {
        static display ( event, target ) {
            if ( event.files[0] ) {
                let fileReader = new FileReader();
                fileReader.onload = function (event) {
                    target.setAttribute( 'src', event.target.result );
                }
                fileReader.readAsDataURL(event.files[0]);
            }
        }

        static ready (wrapper, x, y) {
            x.innerHTML = wrapper.clientWidth;
            y.innerHTML = wrapper.clientHeight;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I still get the value of the old picture's dimensions. It's not about the actual dimensions but to access the NEW image's height and width, no matter id the width is static or dynamic.

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could help! Please consider marking the answer as a solution if it did answer your question, so others can find it more easily.

Answer (score 0):

Try accessing the image itself's `width`, `clientWidth`, or `offsetWidth` property instead of the wrapper.

Comment: Same problem with that.